# Copy a file to all computers in LAN network with Windows CMD

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, lan, network-shares

I need copy a file to the "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" folder of all users in all computers in local network. I have Admin permissions in all computers if is needed, but the idea is to share the file just from one to all of them. I know that i have the command 'net' but i really dont know what i should use to do this process.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point in CMD is something like:

```
xcopy "c:\path\to\file" "\\computername\C$\users\username\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

Or the same thing in Powershell:

```
Copy-Item "c:\path\to\file" "\\$Computername\C$\users\$username\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

There are certainly ways to loop through a list of users/computers, but it depends on how you plan to define and/or get those lists. You could scan the whole local network for example, but it would be extremely slow. There are also a lot of things on the network to consider like firewall settings or whether the PCs are in a windows domain.

---

To check access, try browsing to the remote PC by pasting the UNC path into file explorer: `\\computername\C$\`. If it prompts you for credentials, you will need to provide them as part of your command as well.

For computers not in a windows domain, you usually need to log in with the username formatted like `RemotePCName\Username`. If you are able to log in using windows explorer, then you can try doing the same with Powershell:

```
# This will prompt you for login credentials
$Credential = Get-Credential

# connect to the remote PC as a specific user
New-PSDrive -Name RemotePC -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\RemotePC\C$ -Credential $Credential

# Now copy the file using the connection:
Copy-Item "c:\path\to\file" "RemotePC:\users\$username\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

Comment: using the xcopy command it says denied access, even if both computers dont have password, any idea?

Comment: Have you run it as Admin?

Comment: @harrymc yes, i just was able to copy files, but to just Users/Public/ and shared crap, how can i access to the APPDATA of the other computer?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale oooh, i see things much clare now, but few questions, first, there is any way to automatic detect the user? i mean not the default or the public access user, the main user to access to the appdata. Second, i saw that instead of use the PC name, i can use the local IP, there is any why to scan the network and use a loop to try copy the file to all?

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani  1st, 2nd, 3rd, .... lot questions bro...  you need open a new question... or more than one...

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe I just work for 8 hours straight, write a batch of 200 lines. I t scan all the network from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.255, then use wmic.exe to get Hostname and user and now im working in massive coppy to the Startup folder. Probably my code is realy inefficient, bcs i never use batch before, but is working. Thanks for pass btw!